# Calabash iOS: How to query for all views at offset

Tags: calabash-ios

Is there any way in Calabash to get all views in at some location?

```
for example: query(nil, :offset => {:x => 50, :y => 50})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

And I don't think this is something that we would try to implement.